# Cross Validated asking ad nauseam about accepting cookies?

Tags: bug, popups, cookies

Recently (the last two or three days) on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) (CV) pages, **each time** a new page/tab is opened, it asks anew on accepting cookies. Quite molesting. First I thought it was my browser (Chrome on Ubuntu Linux), but then: This only happens on CV, not even on CV Meta or any other SE sites. So what is going on?

**Edit**

After reading the link to meta SE: I have clicked "Accept all cookies" many times, and it is not remembered. If I click the other option, "Customize", nothing happens...

Comment: It happens sporadically to me on CV but not, as far as I can tell, on other sites. I certainly do not get it every page though. The sites do set separate cookies I think, when I clear out cookies there are ones from loads of SE sites.

Comment: Despite setting up my cookies days ago CV asked me again when I visited; but once they were set it didn't ask again.

Comment: @Luuklag: Not really, that post is linked in my Q--- that post gives no solution to the *ad nauseam*

Comment: Luuk + kjetil, only 4 sites seem to have a link in the footer ([**Cookie Settings**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)) to change your settings (like CV) and other sites don't (like here). --- Probably best as an *answer* (Bug Report) on the *question* (announcement) rather than asking anew; since the announcement is recent. --- kjetil, our (unusual) policy is that you would copy this question to an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent); where Luuklag mentioned.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Could you [edit] your post to include if this happens on the other sites that also have customizable cookies enables at the moment (Super User, Ask Ubuntu, Tex-Latex, and Database Administrators) and confirm your browser [does not block third party cookies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359663/369802) as that's already a reported problem? Copying this to an answer to the question Luuklag linked is one option, but given how this was migrated from another site to here, perhaps just tagging it as a [tag:bug] will get it attention enough :)

Comment: Can you check in your browsers developer console if you have two cookies after you made your choices: `OptanonConsent` and `OptanonAlertBoxClosed` and if those are tied to the `.stackexchange.com` domain?

Comment: @rene: I am not used to the developer console, but I went to settings---security---cookies and other site data--- and searched for cross validated. It lists two cookies only,  notice-m18, sgt only (and some local storage)

Comment: And what are your cookie settings? Those are mentioned on one of the dialogs you clicked through to reach your cookies (good find btw, I didn't know that dialog existed). The problem is the cookies are not set for crossvalidated (or stats.stackexchange.com) but only for the top level domain, .stackexchange. If you take your privacy serious you might have configured Chrome to not allow these cookies.

Comment: @rene: My setting is "Accept all cookies".

Comment: Hmm, okay. That is strange because I would expect the cookies to work then. Are you able to test in a different browser? Something firefox based?  I'm not an Ubuntu user myself so I'm a bit lost at what is possible/available on that OS.

Comment: @rene: I just tried on firefox (installed via synaptic). No problems there!

Comment: Not ad nauseam, but today it asked me ***again*** on the sites mentioned in *[We’re adding more user controls for cookie consent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358)*: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), etc. Given the tight time correlation, a ***common cause*** seems likely. On Firefox 84.0.2 (with [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)) and [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)).

Comment: I'm glad it is not something tied to your account, network, local PC but just an odd browser. Must be setting we're missing.

Comment: No, actually ***sort of*** ad nauseam (but not for every page). Today Ask Ubuntu asked again. (I have been logged into Stack Exchange throughout.)

Comment: uBlock origin's eyedropper tool makes short work of things like cookie banners.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up

Comment: I’ve had the same issue on GD... https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/accept-cookies-ad-nauseam?noredirect=1#comment8331_3754