# What was the teams rationale to using third party cookies in the cookie preference settings?

Tags: support, cookies

There has been a lot of fuzz regarding the cookie consent pop-up lately. One of the reasons for this is that it uses a third party cookie, to store your cookie settings. Some users experience this as problematic, see for example: [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up).

Besides users choosing to block third party cookies due to privacy concerns there are also browsers that have a blanket ban on third party cookies. More will follow as all major browsers will have them [phased out by 2022](https://www.vox.com/recode/2021/3/3/22311460/google-cookie-ban-search-ads-tracking).

Considering this, what was the teams rationale for implementing a third party cookies for storing cookie preferences, instead of opting for a more future-proof option?

Comment: My bet is because it was a "Turn-key" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consent management vendor we chose, [OneTrust](https://www.onetrust.com/), is a widely used and trusted consent management vendor that enables us to meet the applicable regulatory requirements. We cannot discuss their platform, but you can learn more about them by clicking the link provided.

Regarding the issue you raised, [we've implemented a fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363872/312743) for the small percentage of users that were experiencing it.

Comment: Your fix hasn’t worked.  I still experience the same issue daily on all my daily devices. I am not blocking cookies.

Comment: "Widely used" is not the same as "widely trusted". The very fact that a third-party "solution" is used means that that third-party gets to know about all the websites that somebody visits: the avoidance of such a situation is one of the main reasons for having privacy, data protection and cookie laws, which makes me wonder how it can be compliant.