# New cookie nag is not dismissable with some ad-blocking settings

Tags: bug, user-interface, cookies

I use Firefox first-party isolate and UBlock Origin with fairly strong settings (no third-party JS except allow-listed domains, etc.) and the new cookie nag:

[image: Cookie nag]

has buttons that do not work at all. Presumably the settings are being outsourced to some third-party, which is itself something of a privacy concern. But it's frustrating that the UI element itself is local and displayed even with these third-party domains not allowed, while the interactivity isn't, making it impossible to dismiss without debugging it.

So far I've just been blocking the whole thing with the element picker on SE sites I hit it on, but it would be nice if it just worked without relying on third-party domains or if it indicated the domains you need to unblock to make it work (and disclosed that SE is outsourcing this).

Comment: I think most of this has already been reported in the answers to the announcement, mainly https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359701/369802 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359663/369802 ... There's also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/369802, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359691/369802 ... It still would be good to have some kind of official answer/fix for this though.

Comment: It seems like it would be fairly easy to detect that the needed third party JavaScript isn't being loaded and add a notice/button saying something like "It looks like you've disabled loading JavaScript from third parties. Many people who do that want to only allow cookies used for on-site functionality. If you want to only enable cookies which are necessary for on-site functionality, prevent disclosure of information unless necessary for on-site functionality, and to disable all other cookies [click here]."

Comment: @Makyen: Yes, that's exactly how the workflow should be. Of course it would be even better to just get rid of all the third-party trackers for all users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cookielaw.org keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: Personally, I’ve read most of the linked content and decided to just not use the site rather than figure out why two of my OS are ineffective. This might be better if it’s reopened so there can be a thread explaining how to troubleshoot this. All the other answers point to the announcement and [don’t have a step by step process to guide someone that cares to fix this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362864/165931)