# Every Stack Exchange site, StackOverflow, Super User etc continue to asks me for cookie consent even if i accepted multiple times

Tags: support, bug, cookies, cookie-policy

As the title of the question says, every time I visit a site of stack exchange family I get the dialog for cookie consent.

I accepted it multiple times (clicked on "Accept all cookies") but no way, it is still there every time I visit a page on stack exchange network.

Tested with Firefox, chromium.

Comment: Do you allow (thirdparty) cookies? Do you block cookielaw.org?

Comment: probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362406/new-cookie-nag-is-not-dismissable-with-some-ad-blocking-settings

Comment: For me it happened a bit on some odd sites i rarely visit, now they are gone for me. I think you can just wait them out.

Comment: Solution: don't click anything, let it stay there. It's big, but eventually we'll get used to it. ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard thanks nice one, I will draw it on my monitor directly to view it any time even if I am not on stackoverflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cookielaw.org keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up)

Comment: From what I understand It need to be fixed.

Comment: @Cas I made some tests and as you said the issue is with cookielaw.org.  It has to not be blocked or otherwise the popup will continue to appear at each visti. For my case this is the solution if you want to answer this I will accept it