# Captcha's from another domain than documented?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Stack Overflow sometimes asks to verify if you're a human being, especially if a lot of students coming from a proxy server are searching the site. According to [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), `api.recaptcha.net` should be whitelisted. However, in reality it seems that `www.google.com` needs to be whitelisted, which also results in having the search engine available, obviously. It can be tested by visiting https://stackoverflow.com/nocaptcha and using Developer Tools to view the network trace (see screenshot below).

As we sometimes administer programming exams, Stack Overflow is allowed to be used as a resource to resolve certain issues, but having the Google search engine - with all its additional features - available is a bridge too far.

I'm posting this here to accomplish one of two things (hopefully the first):

1. Is it possible to have a captcha system that does not rely on `www.google.com`?
2. OR could the documentation be corrected (which does not help us any further, but at least the documentation is correct).

See the Network tab of Developer tools to have a list of the domains that are being used:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome developer tools showing that www.google.com and www.gstatic.com are being used for the captcha.]

Comment: Re *"Stack Overflow is allowed to be used as a resource"*: In what way? For example, using it actively by asking questions, not just as read-only (logged out)?

Comment: It's intended as read-only, not to get their problems solved by anyone else during an exam.

Comment: So also hit by CAPTCHAs when logged out? Or conversely, especially when logged out? Possibly related: *[Why am I seeing reCAPTCHAs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385626/why-am-i-seeing-recaptchas)* and *[Can something be done to not CAPTCHA every search from DuckDuckGo's bangs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359455/can-something-be-done-to-not-captcha-every-search-from-duckduckgos-bangs)*

Comment: Related: [Why can't SE use a non-Google captcha that invades my privacy less?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335309/why-cant-se-use-a-non-google-captcha-that-invades-my-privacy-less)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum They do not login. Getting the CAPTCHA is not really an issue though. The problem for me is that we have to allow Google access, which is undesirable in this specific case. Thanks for the references though!